# How to use Promise JS in this case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have :

```
function loadDoc123() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
```

I want to implement promiseJS to this code but dont editing code . How do i do?

Answer (score 2):

Without editing you can't. You need to wrap the code into the Promise

```
function loadDoc123() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {            
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                res(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford", true);
        xhttp.send(); 
    });
}
```

And use

```
loadDoc123().then(text => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text);
```